# What Hotpoint oven model is this?

Tags: oven

I need a new oven door for my  Hotpoint electric oven.

I found a supplier, but apart from the Serial Number, the company also want to know the oven model. I've searched the web but cannot find the model of my oven with the exact same control panel as in the attached picture.

I know it's a long shot, but does anyone have any ideas what model this is?

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Open the doors of the oven - the model information should be on an information plate that's usually covered by one of the doors.

Answer (score 1):

## What Hotpoint's website says ...

### Packaging

I went to the hotpoint website and clicked "Register a product" then I clicked the info button next to "model number" and a pop-up message said "this can be found on the packaging of your product"

### Manual, Page 1

I then clicked "model help" and was taken to a page  that stated *"The product model code is located on the first page of the instruction manual."*

### Oven

I then selected "Oven" and it showed me this picture

[image]

It would have been quicker to follow the Evil Greebo's advice!

---

If you google for "hotpoint oven timer" and click "images" you'll soon see this

[image]

So maybe you have something not quite entirely unlike a "Hotpoint SY86P Electric Oven"

Answer (score -1):

It looks more like a SY36/SY37